# Why are these timestamps out of order with Perl Time::HiRes?

Tags: perl, unix, timestamp, ext4

I'm seeing some strange behaviour with the timestamp reported by Perl's `Time::HiRes` module.

I have a script that gets three timestamps:

1. Get timestamp with `Time::HiRes::time`
2. Create a new file, and get its modification time with `Time::HiRes::stat`
3. Get timestamp with `Time::HiRes::time`

I'd expect the timestamps to be ordered`1 < 2 < 3`, however this isn't always the case; often (but not always), the time reported by `stat` in 2. is *before* the timestamp from 1..

I'm on an Ext4 filesystem. Here's an experiment:

```
use Time::HiRes qw/ time stat /;

while( 1 ){
    # t0
    my $t0 = time;

    # Create a file
    my $f = '/tmp/dummy.test';
    open(my $fh, '>', $f) || die;
    print $fh "hi\n";
    close($fh) || die;

    # FS: file modification time, according to the filestystem
    my $fs = (stat($f))[9];

    # t1
    my $t1 = time;

    ## Report how the timestamps relate to each other
    # A. All good
    if( $t0 < $fs && $fs < $t1 ){
       print "$t1,0\n";
    }
    # B. FS before t0
    elsif( $t0 > $fs && $fs < $t1 ){
       print "$t1,1\n";
    }
    # C. FS after t1
    elsif( $t0 < $fs && $fs > $t1 ){
       print "$t1,2\n";
    }
    # D. this should never happen (t0 and t1 probably can't flip)
    elsif( $t0 > $fs && $fs > $t1 ){
       print "$t1,3\n";
    }
}
```

Here are the results of letting the above loop run for a few seconds. where the blue points on the bottom are incidents of the "correct" behaviour. More often than not, I get condition `B`, where the modification time from `stat` is *before* the first timestamp.

[image]

What could explain this behaviour?

**Update:** Here's a plot of the timestamp lags for the fist 2000 iterations:

[image]

Comment: `$t0-$fs, " ", $t1-$fs` show that both $t0 and $t1 are very close to each other, and far ahead of $fs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be because of a difference in the precision of both timestamps as mentioned in the doc [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html#stat):

> As stat or lstat but
>   with the access/modify/change file timestamps in subsecond resolution,
>   if the operating system and the filesystem both support such
>   timestamps. To override the standard stat():
>
> ```
> use Time::HiRes qw(stat);
> ```
>
> Test for the value of &Time::HiRes::d_hires_stat to find out whether the operating system
>   supports subsecond file timestamps: a value larger than zero means
>   yes. There are unfortunately no easy ways to find out whether the
>   filesystem supports such timestamps. UNIX filesystems often do; NTFS
>   does; FAT doesn't (FAT timestamp granularity is **two** seconds).
>
> A zero
>   return value of &Time::HiRes::d_hires_stat means that
>   Time::HiRes::stat is a no-op passthrough for CORE::stat() (and
>   likewise for lstat), and therefore the timestamps will stay integers.
>   The same thing will happen if the filesystem does not do subsecond
>   timestamps, even if the &Time::HiRes::d_hires_stat is non-zero.
>
> In any
>   case do not expect nanosecond resolution, or even a microsecond
>   resolution. Also note that the modify/access timestamps might have
>   different resolutions, and that they need not be synchronized, e.g. if
>   the operations are
>
> ```
> write
> stat # t1
> read
> stat # t2
> ```
>
> the access time stamp from t2 need not be greater-than the modify
>   time stamp from t1: it may be equal or *less*.